# SSRS fixed printing layout

Tags: reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report which is being used to print to a dot matrix printer for shipping (paper has boxes that I need to print info into).  It has a header including customer address, despatch address, date, order no. etc.  Body has product, description, quantity, Footer has No. of Cases/Containers.  Problem is if I have a customer with a long address etc.  it screws up the formatting of the report.  How do I create absolute fixed regions for printing?  I would rather the customer's address was just truncated rather than screwing up the formatting of my report?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the text box, go to Text Box Properties. Untick "Allow height to increase". Drink beer in celebration.

Comment: is it really that simple?  I've seen massive posts about putting hidden boxes, custom code and all sorts... i'll give it a go and let you know!

Comment: Hi this has party solved my issue!  However when the second page prints, the body starts slightly higher up for some reason?  How do I get it to start on the second page the same place as the first page?

Comment: Every sequential page is printing an extra two lines in the body... however the footer and header is still lined up correctly.

Comment: is there a gap between your first report item and the header?

Comment: Formatting and positioning in SSRS sometimes seems to depend on you sacrificing the right number of virgins, proper alignment of the planets etc. In this case however I'd probably say set the report body to be the exact size you want the mailing slip to be (remember to take margins into account), then make sure the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace property is false. This should make sure the report takes your positioning of all the items as gospel truth and doesn't try to move them around against your will.

Comment: lol ok I hate this trial and error stuff it's so time consuming! Dot Matrix printers aren't the fastest either!

Comment: there is a gap between the first item in the body and the header... should i remove this?

Comment: You could do, but provided you're accounting for it in your positioning it shouldn't really matter. Like if you have an A5 page, that's got a height of 21cm with a top and bottom margin of 1cm each. provided the height of the report, including header and body and that gap didn't exceed 19cm, it would be fine to leave it there.

Comment: its that gap not being there on page 2 thats causing everything to be slightly higher. you can either remove the gap and re-align everything, or replicate the gap just after your page break.

Comment: Ok so I'm nearly there... I've removed any extra space in body, which has made equal amount of lines print on each page. Increased header size to push body down and realign text. Now the only problem I'm facing is I'm getting a blank page printing after each page? Weird... Is that anything to do with page or body size? Another weird thing is first column of body is printing in smaller text than rest of table even though I've tried increasing font size dropping re adding etc. is that some sort of bug? The users will live with that for now... Weird though.

Comment: A blank page following each page is, in my experience, usually due to the report being horizontally too wide for the page size you have set. Right click the background and go to Report Properties (I think?) and it should tell you the size you have set there - make sure the body of the report doesn't horizontally exceed that.

Comment: I think that's cracked it!  Thanks for your help!  Any ideas about the smaller font size for first column in body table?  Even if I make it bigger it still seems to stay same size... When I do a print to screen it's highlighted blue like a hyperlink, i don't know why that is/if it's causing issue...

Comment: Best guess about this one is that the report is interpreting some kind of markup? Right click the TEXT (not the textbox) and go to PlaceHolder Properties. You'll see a section called "Markup Type" - set that to "None - Plain text only". You may find you get some tags coming through then like <h7> or something - you'd have to use a replace function to strip 'em out.

Comment: The data in the table can have markup in though, particularly if it's come from a web form.

If that's not the case then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas on that one, sorry. Can't really imagine why else it would format itself like that.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I really would have been lost without it!

Answer (score 0):

not sure on the layout of your report so this might help if you dont want to truncate.

report has a property, ConsumeContainerWhitespace. by default its set to false, this means that when report items like textboxes grow they retain the whitespace and push everything else down.

set to true they will (yep you guessed it) *consume* the whitespace instead. preserving the position of other items.

though if there is no space for the textbox to grow into then the other answer provided offers the best solution